# why is my <object>not shown on iphone?

Tags: iphone, cordova, object

i want to show a forreign website as  in my phonegap App on iphone. I see the Website in the  when i view the app in firefox but there is nothing shown on iphone. Any idea or solutions? (the url is just an example)

```
<div id="divSvgView" dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" style="background-color: #d0d0d0;">
     <object type="txt/html" id="svgObject" data="http://heise.de" style="width:400px; height:400px;margin1%;"></object>
</div>
```

greets Tom

Comment: Maybe because of this: "margin1%;". You're missing a colon there. By the way, phonegap sucks. Go native.

Comment: have you tried using type="application/xhtml+xml"? This seems to be required in some versions of desktop and iOS Safari to get things working.

Comment: @Reid Johnson, that fixed it, many thx! Eli, i am forced to use phonegap, i also dont like it :(

Comment: Glad that fixed it. I went ahead and added my comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using type="application/xhtml+xml"? This seems to be required in some versions of desktop and iOS Safari to get things working.